# Facebook instant game - I'm having trouble uploading files?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-instant-games

when i try to upload the file i get this message:
You must include a bundle config in your upload. To create a bundle config, please refer to:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/bundle-config.
[You must include a bundle config in your upload.
To create a bundle config, please refer    to:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GiFg.png)

this is my index.html file,
I added the code to the index,htmk file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/boostrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/asset/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
    <title>Trắc nghiệm lịch sử</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="vh-100 vw-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="position-relative contai h-100 bg-secondary p-2">
            <div class="px-2 d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <strong class="text-warning">Quiz</strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="text-warning">icon</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="px-2 pt-5">
                <div class="" id="question">
                    <h5 class="text-white"></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pb-4 position-absolute bottom-0 start-0">
                <div class="p-3 row gx-0 g-3" id="option_answer">
                    <!-- <div class="col-6"><button type="button">Lý Nam Đế</button></div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="w-100 text-center">
                    <button type="button" id="submit_answer" >Gửi Đáp án</button>
                    <button type="button" id="next_question" >Tiếp tục</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.7.0.js"></script>
    
    <script src="./fbLoader.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

add fbapp-config.json

`{
"instant_games": {
"platform_version": "RICH_GAMEPLAY",
"orientation": "LANDSCAPE",
"navigation_menu_version": "NAV_FLOATING"
}
}``

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check the folder structure you are uploading; the fbapp-config.json file should be in the root folder